# How to set "timeout" when using the method "CreateSqlStringAccessor"?

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, command-timeout

I have a code like this, how I can do to set the "CommnadTimeout"?

```
var database = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>();
var sqlGetAllPersons = @"select * from Person.Person";
var personMapper = MapBuilder<Person>.MapAllProperties().Build();

// create an accessor (DataAccessor)
var personAccessor = database.CreateSqlStringAccessor<Person>(sqlGetAllPersons, personMapper);

// execute the accessor (IEnumerable<Person>)
var profiles = personAccessor.Execute();
```

(code from [EntLib 5.0 DAAB MapBuilder maps DBNull to null](http://www.shirmanov.com/2010/05/entlib-50-daab-mapbuilder-maps-dbnull.html))

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I like little this solution, I was able to fix it this way:

```
public class ParameterMapperWithCommandTimeout : IParameterMapper
{
    public int CommandTimeout { get; set; }

    public void AssignParameters(DbCommand command, object[] parameterValues)
    {
        command.CommandTimeout = this.CommandTimeout;
    }
}
```

applied to the previous example:

```
var database = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>();
var sqlGetAllPersons = @"select * from Person.Person";
var personMapper = MapBuilder<Person>.MapAllProperties().Build();
var parameterMapper = new ParameterMapperWithCommandTimeout { CommandTimeout = MyTimeOut };

// create an accessor (DataAccessor)
var personAccessor = database.CreateSqlStringAccessor<Person>(sqlGetAllPersons, parameterMapper, personMapper);

// execute the accessor (IEnumerable<Person>)
var profiles = personAccessor.Execute();
```

Comment: This is about the best you're going to get. Accessors are deliberately less than full featured, and don't allow a whole lot of customization. The point you plugged in is pretty much the only place the DbCommand is exposed.